# CSS Jquery AutoComplete - Style not applying

Tags: css

Strange one,
im trying to apply a style to a textbox that is already using jquery autocomplete, the style im trying to apply doe not work, any ideas?

CSS

```
#LongTextbox  {
    width: 250px;
}
```

HTML

```
<input name="ItemEntry_item_${id}" type="text" value="${item}" id="ItemEntry_item_${id}" class="LongTextBox"/>
```

Debug shows

```
<input name="ItemEntry_item_1" type="text" value="" id="ItemEntry_item_1" class="LongTextBox ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off">
```

CSS debug shows no sign of LongTextBox being consumed

Comment: `class="LongTextBox" ` is a class, `#LongTextbox`, the `#` in `CSS` refers to an `ID`

Comment: `#LongTextBox`  should be `.LongTextBox` in CSS

Comment: `#` is for IDs, `.` is for classes. CSS 101.

Comment: I made the change, but still does not make a difference, ideas?

Comment: Also `LongTextBox` != `LongTextbox`

Comment: @D-W You have to check cases as CSS is case sensitive with markup :)

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML has a **class** of LongTextBox (capital B) whereas your CSS is targeting an **id** of LongTextbox (lowercase b).

change CSS to `.LongTextBox` instead of `#LongTextbox`

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6Wgxc/

Answer (score 1):

Change your CSS as below. In CSS `class` is denoted with `.` and `id` is denoted by `#`, further in your CSS code the class name `LongTextBox` is mentioned as `LongTextbox`

**CSS**

```
.LongTextBox  {
    width: 250px;
}
```